# How do you debug a problem in the Activator of an Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I am trying to follow an OSGi bundle tutorial (http://www.vogella.de/articles/OSGi/article.html).  It includes this method in the Activator class:

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Starting de.vogella.osgi.firstbundle");
}
public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Stopping de.vogella.osgi.firstbundle");
}
```

Unfortunately, the println statements don't print even though the tutorial writer expects them to print.  I am obviously new to OSGi and Eclipse, so I am quite lost.  Can someone help me along?

Comment: No, I am following the tutorial which specifies how to load and start.  If you look at the tutorial, you will see that it prints "Hello OSGi" in a separate thread.  This println works.  I have followed the tutorial on down further and am having problems connection to the quoteservice.  That requires that I debug the Activator class.  That is why I'm asking about this much simpler problem.

Comment: @J Edward Ellis - Well, if the plugin is started, then there's no reason why this shouldn't print. Do you see any excpetions in the console?. As for your question, you can debug the Activator class just like any other class - set a breakpoint :).

Comment: Did you add 'Bundle-Activator: yourpackage.Activator' in the MANIFEST.MF of your plug-in?

Comment: Usually services are in different bundles.  Are both bundles started?  If you `bundle` in the console on the bundle providing the service, does it list the exported service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I said I was confused.  The tutorial mentioned above runs the first demo in Eclipse, but quickly shifts to a standalone container.  I got that to work, but broke off for the night and when I came back in the morning started using the built-in OSGi console to follow the standalone instructions.  This doesn't work very well and results in the odd behavior described above.  When I went back to the standalone container as directed in the tutorial it works better.

Answer (score -1):

I'd assume your plugin isn't even started, or eclipse has no reasons to load your plugin (eclipse does lazy loading of plugins so activate a view of your plugin or something).

If it's the first problem make sure that under Run Configurations->Plugins "Launch with all workspace and enabled Plugins" is selected (that's the easiest to make sure that the plugin and its dependencies are all loaded).